# Usage of "AUTOINCREMENT" in sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Reference the SQL code snippet below: 
Is my "AUTOINCREMENT" usuage correct in the context used. If not, can anyone provide suggest me how to?

```
puzzle_table_creator = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Puzzle` (
        `PuzzleNumber` INT NOT NULL ,
        `ImageFileName` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        `Difficulty` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        `NoAttempts` INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT (`PuzzleNumber`)
    ); '''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you have to code `AUTOINCREMENT` at the column level and it can only be coded for a column that is defined specifically using INTEGER (not anything else such as INT or BIGINT) (case insensitive so InTeGer would be fine) AND that is defined as the PRIMARY KEY.

As such you could use

```
puzzle_table_creator = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Puzzle` (
    `PuzzleNumber` INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,
    `ImageFileName` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `Difficulty` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `NoAttempts` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`PuzzleNumber`)
); '''
```

or the more common :-

```
puzzle_table_creator = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Puzzle` (
    `PuzzleNumber` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,
    `ImageFileName` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `Difficulty` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `NoAttempts` INT NOT NULL
); '''
```

**However, it is highly unlikely that you need the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword.** Using `AUTOINCREMENT` introduces inefficiencies (see below). Therefore, there is a likeliehood that the better solution is using :-

```
puzzle_table_creator = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Puzzle` (
    `PuzzleNumber` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
    `ImageFileName` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `Difficulty` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `NoAttempts` INT NOT NULL
); '''
```

or

```
puzzle_table_creator = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Puzzle` (
    `PuzzleNumber` INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    `ImageFileName` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `Difficulty` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `NoAttempts` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`PuzzleNumber`)
); '''
```

## AUTOINCREMENT in SQLite

In SQLite `AUTOINCREMENT` is unlike other databases.

Other databases use AUTOINCREMENT (or it's equivalent) to indicate that the column should automatically increment when the row is inserted.

In SQLite, every table (with the exception of  [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) tables ) column, called **rowid** that is normally hidden. This column will be 1 when the first row is inserted and then likely 2 and then likely 3 and so on. The column is implicitly unique so the same number cannot use used.

The **rowid** can be aliased, this is done by specifying `the_column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and as such just coding this closely assimilates the use of `AUTOINCREMENT` in other databases.

- As per the suggested better option.

What `AUTOINCREMENT` does in SQLite is to add a constraint/rule that the value must always be greater than any that value that has been used for the table. It does this by using a table, created if necessary, called **sqlite_sequence**. The sqlite_sequence table will contain one row per table with a column (seq) for the highest **rowid**.

Without `AUTOINCREMENT` sqlite effectively uses `rowid = max(rowid) + 1` when inserting a row.

- note that when the maximum value (9223372036854775807) is reached a random unused value is used (if there is one (there should be due to device capacity))

When `AUTOINCREMENT` is coded SQLite effectively uses `rowid = max(rowid,(SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = the_table_name)) + 1` which is less efficient as the sqlite_sequence table has to be accessed.

- note if the maximum value is reached and an attempt is made to insert a row an SQLITE_FULL error will occur.

## NOTE

There is no guarantee that rowid will monotoncially increase.

You may wish to read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) which has it's first senetence :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.